# Confusion related to reproducing kernels

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I was reading this paper and I came across Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space. I tried to read some references related to it. However, I couldn't understand much. I didn't get why they are called reproducing kernels. Can anyone give me any pointers or easy references or explain a bit .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually the word ``reproducing'' is justified in terms of the relation
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \langle f, K^x \rangle
\end{equation}
for $f$ in $H$, where $H$ is the reproducing kernel Hilbert space, $K$ is the reproducing kernel of $H$ and $K^x(y) := K(y,x)$.